# Why does Firefox reset my search provider settings to the installation default regularly?

Tags: firefox, 18.04, search

Firefox resets my search provider settings to the default after creating a new profile approx. every 6 months. It adds the removed providers Twitter and Ecosia and removes added providers like Wikipedia (de). Some search added providers remain (e.g. my personal dokuwiki instance).

The reset seems to happen between restarts of the browser for no apparent reason. I experienced this 5 to 10 times over the last years, i.e. in a few Ubuntu releases.

Since the issue happened today, I could make sure that it's not connected to add-on updates (bravo Firefox for no providing a table view of add-ons with easy accessible information

Comment: See if https://ecosia.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004499093-Why-did-Ecosia-stop-working-in-Firefox-57-0-1- or https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1419941 offer any clues.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for your input. Both bugs refer to situations after upgrading from < 57.x. They partly describe what's happening to me randomly without any connection to software or add-on updates (updated the question).

Comment: If you type `about:support` in the address bar and hit `Enter` you'll see, among other things, a list of extensions. And `about:addons` has a cog wheel with options to view an extension's update history.